# using Navigation property to get Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am creating  App using Entity Framework.I have loaded the Database model from Database.here In the `Course` table `Department` is the `Navigation Property`,`DepartmentID` is the foreign key.I have created a gridview and set its Datasource to Course Table,but I want to see the `Deaptment Name` instead of `department ID`.I can use the Navigation properties like `Department.count` but how can I use the navigation property to get data (Department name) from Department Table.
Any one who can help me with this
THIS IS MY CODE

```
       var result = (from o in ctx.Courses.Include("Department")
                     where o.Title == TextBox2.Text
                      select o
                      ).First();

        //GridView4.DataSourceID="";
        GridView3.DataSource=result;

        GridView3.DataBind();
```

If I dont use the First Function then i can't access the Department Name attribute,If i use the First() It say that

```
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

please tell me how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from c in dbContext.Course
             select c).First();
if(!result.Department.IsLoaded)
   {
      result.Department.Load(); //this will load the course.Department navigation property

   }

//Assuming you have 1 - 1 relationship with course to department
string departmentName = result.Department.Name;
```

or if you have 1 - M relationship with the department then:

```
foreach(Department d in result.Department)
{
Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
}
```

EDIT: 

 Instead of trying to load Department do the following

```
if(!result.DepartmentReference.IsLoaded)
{
result.DepartmentReference.Load()
}
```

[How to: Explicitly Load Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896249)

Comment: OSU   No isLoaded property exist :(

Comment: @user1391118, are you using EF 4.0 ?

Comment: I am using the one that comes with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I think Products and Categories tables in Northwind are similar than your need. I would write a query like this:

```
        var ctx = new NorthwindEntities();
        var query = from prod in ctx.Products
                    where prod.ProductName.StartsWith("C")
                    select new { prod.ProductName, prod.UnitPrice, prod.Category.CategoryName };
```

Comment: @user1391118 Maybe I'm missed something, but my sample is the following. Products table has CategoryID foreign key to Category table. You don't have to do any join to access the "parent" table (where category name exist), just to access it from prod.Category navigation property